# UrlRewriting how to build correct redirect with sub folders

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco

Hi I am a new one UrlRewriting, I have old urls like

1. http://www.domaine.com/data.aspx
2. http://www.domaine.com/data/page1.aspx
3. http://www.domaine.com/data/page1/page2.aspx
4. http://www.domaine.com/data/page2.aspx

I changed *data* to *new-data*
how to build UrlRewriting congig for correct redirect to

1. http://www.domaine.com/new-data.aspx
2. http://www.domaine.com/new-data/page1.aspx
3. http://www.domaine.com/new-data/page1/page2.aspx
4. http://www.domaine.com/new-data/page2.aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the following rule to the `/config/UrlRewriting.config` file:

```xml
<add name="datarewrite" 
    virtualUrl="^~/data(.*).aspx" 
    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
    destinationUrl="~/new-data$1.aspx" 
    ignoreCase="true" />
```

Although to ensure that only files within the data folder are added along with *only* the root page, and not any other root files that happen to start with data (e.g. `~/dataflow.aspx` -> `~/new-dataflow.aspx`). You'll want to add these two rules instead:

```xml
<add name="datarewrite" 
    virtualUrl="^~/data.aspx" 
    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
    destinationUrl="~/new-data.aspx" 
    ignoreCase="true" />

<add name="datafolderrewrite" 
    virtualUrl="^~/data/(.*).aspx" 
    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
    destinationUrl="~/new-data/$1.aspx" 
    ignoreCase="true" />
```

Comment: Goran Mottram do you know the way to use Cyrillic chars inside of UrlRewriting.config ?

Comment: @cleric - Updated answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @cleric - I moved the answer to your other question.